# Convert array data to object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

so I have this array.

```
["2020-01-31 18:31:01", "2020-02-03 14:04:30", "2020-02-04 05:58:48", "2020-02-04 14:11:16"]
```

and I like to convert it to object.

```
0: {date: "2020-01-31", time: ["8:31:01"]}
1: {date: "2020-02-03", time: ["4:04:30"]}
2: {date: "2020-02-04", time: ["5:58:48", "14:11:16"]}
```

But I 'm getting this result

```
0: {date: "2020-01-31", time: "8:31:01"}
1: {date: "2020-02-03", time: "4:04:30"}
2: {date: "2020-02-04", time: "5:58:48"}
```

This is my code

```
var times = response.data.time;
var dates = [];
var t = [];
var d = '';
var newData = [];
times.forEach(time => {

   var da = time.substring(0, 10);
   var ti = time.substring(12, 19);

   if(d == da) {

     t.push(ti);

   } else {

     d = da

     var dt = {date: da, time: ti};
     newData.push(dt);

   }


 });
```

I'm having a hard time to figure this out hope you can help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function:

```js
const array = ["2020-01-31 18:31:01", "2020-02-03 14:04:30", "2020-02-04 05:58:48", "2020-02-04 14:11:16"];

const newData = array.reduce((acc, cur) => {
 const [date, time] = cur.split(' ');
 const dateObj = acc.find(e => e.date === date);
 if (dateObj) {
  dateObj.time.push(time);
 } else {
  acc.push({ date, time: [time] });
 }
 return acc;
}, []);

console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 3):

Almost a copy of Hao Wu's solution, but faster, as it does not rely on linear `find`. The values are accumulated into an object, allowing for fast lookups, and then an array is extracted using `Object.values`:

```js
const array = ["2020-01-31 18:31:01", "2020-02-03 14:04:30", "2020-02-04 05:58:48", "2020-02-04 14:11:16"];

const newData = Object.values(array.reduce((acc, cur) => {
 const [date, time] = cur.split(' ');
 if (!acc[date]) {
    acc[date] = { date, time: [] };
  }
  acc[date].time.push(time);
 return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(newData);
```